# Queue Messaging delete message after all subscribers retrieve it

Tags: apache-kafka, queue, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm new in Queue Messaging Call it RabbitMQ, Service Bus, Kafka, etc. I'm trying to look for a solution that will allow m to send messages (queue/topic) to specific subscriber/receivers and the queue/topic will be delete after all my subscribers have received the message. Like,

Producer -> Q1 for sub1 and sub2 only. sub2 retrieve the meesage, then sub1 retrieve the message. Now, message gets deleted. My subscribers can be more than 2. So Is there a messaging solution that helps with this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to delete the message after consuming it? Using something like Apache Kafka you can consume messages from multiple applications independently, and Kafka tracks which messages you've consumed (so as to not duplicate them). The benefit of not deleting them is that you can reprocess them if you need to (e.g. your code has a bug and needs to reprocess). The benefit is also that you can use the same data elsewhere in your systems, e.g. to land it to a datastore for analytics, etc.

Here's a [reference comparing Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/comparing-confluent-platform-with-traditional-messaging-middleware/) with other messaging solutions.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for link to the white paper.